# Why do I get: An SMTP To address is required to send a message. "Set the message smtp_envelope_to, to, cc, or bcc address."?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, learn-ruby-on-rails

I am following the learn Ruby on Rails book by Daniel Kehoe and when I try to send mail, I get the following error.

> ArgumentError at /contacts An SMTP To address is required to send a
>   message. Set the message smtp_envelope_to, to, cc, or bcc address.

The better errors gem points to `UserMailer.contact_email(@contact).deliver` in the Contacts Controller.

I have done some research and prior to the error had followed the book's instruction on setting the environmental variables in my .bash_profile file.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update**

As per the responses, thank you. I had already set the mail (to: )

```
def contact_email(contact)
  @contact = contact
  mail(to: Rails.application.secrets.owner_email, from: @contact.email, :subject => "Website Contact")
end
```

And I set the smtp settings:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: Rails.application.secrets.domain_name,
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username,
  password: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_password
}
```

**Update 2**

Thanks. Find secrets below :) I excluded the secret key base here

```
development:
  email_provider_username: <%= ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"] %>
  email_provider_password: <%= ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"] %>
  domain_name: example.com
  mailchimp_api_key: <%= ENV["MAILCHIMP_API_KEY"] %>
  mailchimp_list_id: <%= ENV["MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID"] %>
  owner_email: <%= ENV["OWNER_EMAIL"] %>
  secret_key_base: 'my secret key_base'


test:
  secret_key_base: 'my secret key_base'

production:
  email_provider_username: <%= ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"] %>
  email_provider_password: <%= ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"] %>
  domain_name: <%= ENV["DOMAIN_NAME"] %>
  mailchimp_api_key: <%= ENV["MAILCHIMP_API_KEY"] %>
  mailchimp_list_id: <%= ENV["MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID"] %>
  owner_email: <%= ENV["OWNER_EMAIL"] %>
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Comment: Are you setting the `to:` option to a valid email when calling `mail()` in your mailer?

Comment: Thank you. I did. Please see the update above

Comment: Show your secrets.yml

Comment: @infused thank you for the formatting. After your formatting I am more aware of how to do the formatting. Thanks and sorry for the terrible formatting.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev please see the secrets file. Thanks

Comment: Well, secrets.yml doesn't reveal much, does it? What is `ENV['OWNER_EMAL']`? Is it set?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for your assistance. I did some digging and stumbled on a solution

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through some detective workI stumbled on a solution that only required me to restart terminal

The problem is as described as above. Earlier I had filled out the following environmental variables in my .bash_profile file.

```
export GMAIL_USERNAME="my_email@gmail.com"
export GMAIL_PASSWORD="my_password"
export MAILCHIMP_API_KEY="my mail_chimp_api_key"
export MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID="my mail_chimp_list_id"
export OWNER_EMAIL="my_email@gmail.com"
```

But it app wasn't able to access these variables somehow.

I came across and typed the following command in terminal

```
> env
```

It lists all the environmental variables in your pc environment. (I think)

Anyway I saw the variables above that I had set which meant that my variables were properly set and it was just the app that was unable to access the variables.

After some more digging, I came across this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/106823) that said something about restarting terminal.

I tried that and it worked.

The lesson learned is that when I alter environmental variables, I should restart my terminal.

I hope this helps others.